# OpenCV created videos not playing in browser

Tags: html, video, browser

I have created a video using opencv-python in AVI format. When I open the video locally, it is playing. But when I embed this video to HTML5, it is not playing.

How can I fix this?

I have tried in both Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: What is the format of the video you created?

Comment: video is avi format

Comment: this video is created by opencv python , normal avi video is playing in browser

Comment: i again created mp4 format video , it also not supporting

Comment: It may help if you can share the code for creating the video and for embedding it on HTML5.

Comment: <video src="/static/output.mp4" controls type="video/avi">
 </video>

Comment: I've also got the same issue.